# jquery modal dialog background does not extend beyond iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm working on a web app that uses iframes. I wrote a modal dialog function using the jQuery library, which triggers a modal popup window inside the iframe.  Everything works except the dialog background, when the modal window is triggered, only covers the portion inside the iframe.

This is expected behavior and I thought the fix would be relatively easy with changing the z-index values, but I cannot escape the modal background outside the iframe. The code is pretty straightforward, I'll paste a bit here.

I should specify that our source tree only has access to the iframe, we inherit from parent elements/controls, but cannot access them, so I am limited to whatever the fix would be inside the iframe.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="CloudContent" runat="server">
<!--This triggers the modal dialog-->
<div class="cloudinfo"><a href="#dialog" name="modalbox">Add Cloud-Based Application</a></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: website is hosted?would have checked online the scenario and fix it in a minute..

Comment: Sadly, no, it is a private portal

Comment: The modal dialog is scopped to the iframe that triggers it, so only the iframe is covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continued experimentation :-), a CSS change did the trick.  Changing the position to "fixed" from "absolute" resolved it.  A snippet of CSS below, and I hope this helps someone else.

```
#modalBackground {
    z-index:1000; 
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    background-color:#000;
    display:none;
}
```